# Obj and No Obj fields in YOLOv2 darknet always 0

Tags: image-processing, object-detection, darknet

I am training YOLOv2 model on custom data. It has 6 classes of data. I follow [AlexyAB's darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) to train for custom training. The dataset I am using is [COQE dataset](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-vision-datasets/COQE_dataset/COQE_dataset.tar.gz) mentioned in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02718.pdf).

The problem I am facing is whenever I start training the Obj and No-Obj attribute goes to zero.

In the cfg file, my batch=64, subdivisions=8, filters=55, classes=6, everything else is similar to yolo-voc.vfg

[image: Training Yolov2]